# How to display an android compound control as a single view item in hierarchyviewer

Tags: android, view, controls

I've created a simple compound control containing an EditText and a Button underneath it, that clears whatever text is on the EditText view.

Everything works fine, but what i want to do is view this compound control as a whole (or single view) in hierarchy viewer, but whenever i load this, i see my custom control (which extends LinearLayout), and also the two sub views it contains.

I know its possible to do what i want because i have seen it in the Gmail application, which uses a custom view (CanvasConversationHeaderView) to display email items inside the ListView.

I need to do this because in my case my custom compound control contains a lot more single views than this example so i need to decrease the number of total views in my activity.

I hope someone can help me as to how to accomplish this.

Comment: And what is the problem with the way hierarchyviewer shows you the _hierarchy_ ?

Comment: there is actually no problem, but i want to be able to see this as a leaf in the tree instead of a node with multiple childs or leafs, this way decreasing the number of total views in my activity

Comment: The number of views in your activity would be the same no matter how hierarchviewer display them. Is this what you mean?

Comment: I'm sorry if i'm not explaining myself correctly. If you load hirarchyviewer on the Gmail app, you can see CanvasConversationHeaderView be treated as a single view item, but you can see that it contains multiple view items within itself, but those are not counted as views for the total number of views in screen, and that is exactly what i want to accomplish.

Comment: If I had to guess, I would say CanvasConversationHeaderView is a View that uses a Canvas to draw itself, not a ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know `CanvasConversationHeaderView` from gmail is a compound view?

If by compound view you are refering to [`ViewGroup`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.html), then that's how hierarchyviewer works, it traverses the tree treating `ViewGroup` as internal nodes and `View` as leafs. If you don't want this behaviour then don't extend from `ViewGroup` (`LinearLayout` in this case).

Comment: What i mean is that it's a view containing other views, and i know this because i heard Romain Guy mention this in a Google I/O conference in 2009. So you are saying that if i want to see this as a leaf in the tree i must inherit from view and manually layout and draw the child views?